# How to refresh durable function key "durabletask_extension" using Az Cli

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

We are facing a strange issue with one of our Az Functions. We are using a durable functions which it does have several AppKeys configured, one of them is called "durabletask_extension".

We are trying to automate the refresh of the keys using Az Cli but apparently when we try to refresh the key - the shell gives an error like "Operation Returned an invalid status "NotFound" "

However, I can see from listing the keys that the key-name provided is supposed to be correct.

Kindly see images attached :)

is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Refresh of default or master keys seems to be working just fine.

***Images:***

Keys List:-
[image]

Keys Set:-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly set a System key:
'The scope of system keys is determined by the extension, but it generally applies to the entire function app. System keys can only be created by specific extensions, and you can't explicitly set their values.'
(read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4#system-key))

See these related Github issues:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23693
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/23107#issuecomment-1177076620

Answer (score -1):

*We are able to reproduce the issue*,

[image]

***The key name which you have provided is `systemKeys` which is automatically managed by the Function runtime.***

[image]

[image]

*Instead, of that we have tried with `functionkeys` and it just worked fine with the same keyname `"durabletask_extension"` which we can add in our function app* .

[image]

**NOTE:-** ***To add `masterKey` as in your functions you can use the below cmdlts***.

```
az functionapp function keys set -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFunctionAppName --function-name MyFunctionName --key-name systemKey --key-value MyKeyValue
```

[image]

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **MS DOC**| [**az functionapp keys set**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#code-try-3).& [**az functionapp function keys set**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-keys-set) .

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your reply.

I tried that - however it does solve the issue partially.

as the command create a new key called "durabletask_extension" under the HostKeys.

I endup having 2 keys named "durabletask_extension" one in the SystemKeys and one in the HostKeys.

I understand that SystemKeys are managed by the runtime - however, I'm able to renew it from the Portal GUI .. weird that it cannot be done from the CLI :(

Comment: Yes,From Portal GUI we can add the host keys in function app and from the CLI as well. But to use in `cmd` we need function app>functions where we can use the `systemkey`.

Comment: no, I meant that from the portal .. I can see a key called "durabletask_extension" under the SystemKeys.

which it's the key that I'm interested into ... I can also renew it from the portal and the key would change.

however that's not possible from the CLI apparently. Also none of my functions has key called "durabletask_extension" if I try to search it in function app>functions.

it does exist only on the "main" function level